# Angular: set @Output from code

Tags: angular

Can I somehow set a child component's `@Output()` property from `parent.component.ts` without having to write `(something)="doSmething()"` in its HTML file? I need this for dynamic components.

Maybe with `ContentChildren`, `ViewChildren`, `ViewContainerRef` or `EmbeddedViewRef` with a selector?

Comment: can you explain your problem with more information

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

```
createChild() {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
    const ref = this.location.createComponent(factory);
    ref.something.subscribe(event => this.doSmething());
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    return ref;
}
```

Comment: I'm using something like this: `row.createEmbeddedView(cell.template, {$implicit: someData});`, where `row` is a `ViewChild`, and `cell` is a `Directive`.

Comment: what is resolver?